# lock screen vs home button and backgrounding problems

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios4

My app runs an NSTimer that updates the screen, but I want to stop it when the user exits the program and start it up again **if necessary** when the user comes back in. It seems that `-applicationDidEnterBackground` is called when the home button is pushed, but not if the user just locks the screen. I think `-applicationDidResignActive` is called on screen lock. Is there a way to use these well? or do I just need put the code in both places. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` is called whenever your app is interrupted. This includes locking the screen, receiving a phone call or push notification (on iOS 3 or 4), as well as when the application is moved to the background. Putting your code there is sufficient to stop the timer for all cases.

For reactivating your timer, you should use `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`, which is called whenever your application is reactivated, including when it is first launched.